# Assign groups based on a list of paired values between all individual group entries

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a tab-separated file `pairs.tsv` with two columns that display paired entries. Based on the two values in the two columns, I want to create a third column that assigns groups to the entries.

In some cases however more than two entries belong to the same group. The script should accordingly start at line 1 and assign `group01` to the first pair and then check through the remaining lines if either of the two values from column 1 or 2 appear and if true, also assign `group01` to this line.

This step should be repeated until all entries in the file affiliated to `group01` by iteratively detecting pairs are assigned to `group01`.

Then the script should proceed with the next line and if no group was assigned yet, assign it to `group02` and then again check through the remaining file, if the entry of column 1 or 2 in line 2 appears in any of the lines below and if yes assign also `group02` to the line. And so on.

`pairs.tsv`:

```
a   b
c   d
e   f
e   g
h   i
h   j
k   l
f   g
m   n
i   j
```

The output file should look like this:

```
a   b   group01
c   d   group02
e   f   group03
e   g   group03
h   i   group04
h   j   group04
k   l   group05
f   g   group03
m   n   group06
i   j   group04
```

Comment: What should the output look like if line 6 is `h a` instead of `h j`? Could a line have two groups assigned to it?

Comment: If the 2nd row of input was `c b` instead of `c d` should the output for that row be `c b group02` or should it be `c b group01` since `b` is present in `group01` from the first line? You currently have 2 different answers that produce the same output for the input you posted but work very differently as they're based on different interpretations of your requirements and so would produce different output given that one small change in the input.

Comment: See the alternative input I added to the bottom of my answer for cases for you to consider and [edit] your question to include.

Answer (score 2):

You only need one pass through the input file to do this:

```
awk -F'\t' '{ 
  # "groups" is an associative array containing the group numbers
  # for the values in fields $1 and $2.
  if (! ($1 in groups)) {
     # "gc" stands for "group counter"
     groups[$1] = ++gc;
  }

  groups[$2] = groups[$1]

  printf "%s\t%s\tgroup%02i\n", $1, $2, groups[$1];
}' pairs.tsv
a       b       group01
c       d       group02
e       f       group03
e       g       group03
h       i       group04
h       j       group04
k       l       group05
f       g       group03
m       n       group06
i       j       group04
```

---

I also wrote a perl version that uses a hash (associative array) called `%groups` like the awk version, **and** an Array-of-Arrays (AoA - i.e. an array where each element is another array) called `@pairs` to hold the pairs for each group.  Instead of printing out the results as it reads them in, it prints them all out at the end after all input has been read:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $gc = 1; # group counter
my %groups; # hash containing group numbers for each element
my @pairs;  # array of arrays containing pairs

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($a,$b) = split /\t/;

  $groups{$a} = $gc++ unless (defined($groups{$a}));

  $groups{$b} = $groups{$a};
  push @{ $pairs[$groups{$a}] }, [ $a, $b ];
};

END {
  for my $g (keys @pairs) {
    for my $p (@{ $pairs[$g] }) {
      printf "%s\t%s\tgroup%02i\n", @$p[0], @$p[1], $g;
    }
  };
}
```

Because it iterates over the @pairs array, the output is sorted by group number:

```
$ ./group.pl pairs.tsv 
a       b       group01
c       d       group02
e       f       group03
e       g       group03
f       g       group03
h       i       group04
h       j       group04
i       j       group04
k       l       group05
m       n       group06
```

Other than being sorted, the output is identical for both versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, both options solve the problem and your comments in the script are very helpful to me to understand the code and hopefully improve my own awk and perl scripting skills!

Comment: @sara if this is the best answer for your issue please remember to accept it with the tick mark

Answer (score 0):

Based on one possible interpretation of your requirements and using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    grp = ""
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        if ( $i in val2grp) {
            grp = val2grp[$i]
            break
        }
    }
    if ( grp == "" ) {
        grp = ++grps
    }
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        if ( !($i in val2grp) ) {
            val2grp[$i] = grp
        }
    }
    printf "%s%sgroup%02d\n", $0, OFS, grp
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk pairs.tsv
a       b       group01
c       d       group02
e       f       group03
e       g       group03
h       i       group04
h       j       group04
k       l       group05
f       g       group03
m       n       group06
i       j       group04
```

Consider this input, though:

```
$ cat pairs2.tsv
a       b
c       b
d       c
```

Is the following the expected output or not:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk pairs2.tsv
a       b       group01
c       b       group01
d       c       group01
```

If not, why not? On line 1 `b` is assigned to `group01`, then `b` is also present on line 2 so that should also be `group01` which means that `c` is in `group01`, then on line 3 `c` is already in `group01` from line 2 so the whole line 3 (and so also `d`) are then associated with `group01`.

Comment: Thanks for providing a script. Yes, the output from your script fro pairs2.tsv is correct, the pair c-d should also be assigned to group01.

Comment: You're welcome. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do net.